# S/MIME Email Encryption in Thunderbird

Tags: linux, command-line, email, security, thunderbird

I set up a [CA](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/sign-server-and-client-certificates.html) and issued it to Thunderbird.  Now, I need to assign the public and private keys that I generated to Thunderbird.

I'm in settings - Security - Then when I select Digital Signing or Encryption I get

[image]

I started a [blog](https://www.blogger.com/blog/post/edit/2588152628587115105/1865854090347226338) for anyone that wants to go down the rabbit hole of notes.

This might be something as simple as me moving the key from /ca/...to my ~/Documents directory.  I moved one of the files but it would not load into Thunderbird.

This is the part I'm at "Deploying the certificate" which basically means put into Thunderbird

[image]

Please help.  Been stuck on this for a week.
[Certified Authority Tutorial](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/sign-server-and-client-certificates.html)

Comment: Have you tried to build a .p12 / PKCS#12 file (-> OpenSSL) and import it in Thunderbird? BTW: How many users will be in your CA? If there are less than 100 users the recommended way is to use PGP/GnuPG.

Comment: Not yet.  I was not aware of that.  Is a .12 file a Windows thing? Dagmar in #linux Freenode said to use open sll.  I opened the man page and boom it was there s/mime encryption.  Now how to use the tool? Next level for me.  Will be lot's of users for certificates issued out.

Comment: No, PKCS#12 is not related to Windows. It is more that most Linux applications use OpenSSL and OpenSSL prefers PEM format. For conversion pem cert+key -> PKSC#12 see superuser.com. There are a lot of solutions.

Comment: Okay sweet.  I saw openssl has a s/mime feature.  Dagmar in #irc freenode said not to use PKCS#12 and that Openssl would do that so I got curious and saw s/mime functionality.  Problem is I don't know how to use it.  I'm just not that good bro kinda thing.

Comment: I see smime and pkcs12 are standard commands in openssl

Comment: I'm trying to export my keys to a pkcs12 file so I can import them into Thunderbird to have smime encryption.  I keep getting bottle-necked with the same error.  I don't think the .pfx file is correct, that's a Windows server file.  "OpenSSL>  pkcs12 -export -out mypfxcert.pfx -inkey www.macdougall.ninja.key.pem -in  www.macdougall.ninja.cert.pem -certfile intermediate.cert.pem | Error opening input file www.macdougall.ninja.cert.pem 
<powerhouse> www.macdougall.ninja.cert.pem: No such file or directory error in pkcs12"